# I am asking ...you know... but what is it if it is not 'dysfluency'?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I did not know what dysfluency is before I asked [this question and got an answer.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24210/what-is-the-term-for-a-a-a-in-speech)

Well, now I want a term for a special phrase or words that people keep on repeating when they speak. The most common words are `"...you know..."`

> When I was a kid...***you know***... I was very shy. My father...***you know***...was an outspoken person. He always insisted me...***you know***...to be brave and straightforward...

The best example is here, [a Sunder Pichai video](https://www.facebook.com/bhan.shereen/videos/1054742637904417/). Worth noting that there's *dysfluency* as well!

I lost counting the number of ***'you knows'*** in his speech! :)

Comment: **[Filler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_(linguistics))**: "In linguistics, a **filler** is a sound or word that is spoken in conversation by one participant to signal to others that he/she has paused to think but has not yet finished speaking." In Russian, we call them *[slova-parasity](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B)*, or "parasitic words*. So it was, like, very easy: I just opened the Wikipedia page in Russian, then, you know, used the interwiki. (0:

Comment: P.S. By the way, I've just read your question on disfluency, and Snailboat mentions **filler** in her answer there.. P.P.S. And others mention it too.

Comment: Maybe you want to learn some more colloquial designations of this term, less formal than **filler**. Let's hear if there are any from native speakers.

Answer (score 9):

> **[Filler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_(linguistics)):** "In linguistics, a **filler** is a sound or word that is spoken in conversation by one participant to signal to others that he/she has paused to think but has not yet finished speaking." (Wikipedia)

In Russian, we call them *[slova-parasity](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B)*, or *parasitic words*. So it was, like, very easy: I just opened the Wikipedia page in Russian, then, you know, used the interwiki. (0:

Comment: +1 A generic term which embraces *fillers* and other sorts of extra-syntactic interpolations is [*discourse marker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker).

Answer (score 2):

Also the term "vocalized pauses" could apply here, though in my experience that has usually translated to "um, hmm, ah" kind of words/sounds.

For example in public speaking it is common for people to be giving a speech, lose their place and say something like " and to continue the point ... um ... I would like to say ... um ..."